# Flutter: CupertinoTabBar does not disappear when moving to the next screen

Tags: flutter, cupertinotabbar

I'm running the Flutter Gallery example from Google:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_demo.dart

In the gif below, notice how when I navigate from one screen to the next, the Cupertino Tab Bar stays at the bottom of the screen.
The reason why this is the case is that it is a widget that lays within the parent widget CupertinoNavigationDemo and while the tabs are swapped in and out of the view, the tab bar remains.

Is there a way to get rid of the Tab Bar when navigating?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just using Navigator.push and creating new Scaffold without TabBar in a new route

Answer (score 22):

set `rootNavigator: true`

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => "your new routes",
    ));
```

Comment: This should be the answer :)

Comment: This is not entirely correct. It disables the navigation bar transition, because both navigation bars are then in different navigators.