# How to push a full-screen page that stays on top of Flutter BottomNavigationBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I searched everywhere and could not come up with an answer.

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` and a `FloatingActionButton`.

What I am trying to do is pushing a full screen page when the user presses the `FloatingActionButton`.

This page needs to cover the area of the `BottomNavigationBar` and previous `AppBar` since in this new page user is not allowed to go to the other tabs of the `BottomNavigationBar`.

I came across [`fullscreenDialog`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRoute/fullscreenDialog.html), a property of `PageRoute` Widget class and got excited but could not get it to exactly work as I wanted it to work(top<->bottom as I will explain later)

This page will have it's own `Scaffold` and `AppBar` and is able to push/pop to next screens(inside of it's own navigation tree)

In order to pop this page, the user will press a 'x' button positioned at bottom center of the page.

I want to push/pop this new Page from top<->bottom instead of the usual navigation style which is left<->right (For iOS/Cupertino)

I am familiar with this type of UI from iOS devices(`ModalViewController`)

So How would we implement the push and pop commands?

Or is there another, better/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try `MaterialPageRoute` with `fullscreenDialog` prop [(docs)](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRoute/fullscreenDialog.html):

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return new AddEntryDialog();
  },
  fullscreenDialog: true
));
```

Might not be the best way in your case, but it will appear above the bottom bar and any other navigation widgets.

Code taken from: https://marcinszalek.pl/flutter/flutter-fullscreendialog-tutorial-weighttracker-ii/

Comment: This worked thanks:) Do you know of a method to disable the automatically generated 'x' close button at the left side of the AppBar?

Comment: @aytunch Glad it worked! You could try setting `appBar: AppBar(leading: null)` for `Scaffold` in the dialog widget class.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, and it was solved with this:

```
await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator:true).push( // ensures fullscreen
      CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return MyWidget();
            }
      ) );
```

Found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017488/247451

Comment: This one deserves an upvote as well, if you are dealing with multiple Navigators then you will need a way to access the rootNavigator. I wasn't aware of `rootNavigator`. Thanks!

Comment: It works as I expected!!! very very thanks and rootNavigator is very proper to show full screen page even using CupertinoTabScaffold!. Thanks again!

Comment: This is the most simple and correct method.

Comment: Note that using the root navigator breaks screen tracking for analytics, because it can't provide a correct previous route on `RouteObserver.didPop`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. works like a charm. even with customPageRoutes